# Using GD and ImageMagick together

Tags: php, imagemagick, gd

While working on several projects that needed to work with images (re-size, crop, scale, etc) I found that GD does not work well with large images but ImageMagick is slower than GD with smaller ones.

So I thought that I could make a script that could work with both (GD and ImageMagick).  If I've got large image file, my script will use ImageMagick otherwise GD. But everything has its bad side. So what is the bad side of this but slightly growing development time?

Comment: Increases development time, software complexity, dependency on third party libraries, rate of upgrades required as third-party libraries have vulnerabilities or bugs discovered.  Non of this is rocket science.  If performance is REALLY that important to you, build a hybrid.  Perhaps as a library so that you're always using your own functions rather than directly calling anything from GD or IMgk.

Comment: Thank you, Graham. Yes, performance is what I need. And I disagree with dependency, because I will use my own class so I can easily replace third party library in my methods that won't affect on my project.

Comment: You asked for the "bad side".  Are you suggesting that increasing dependencies is not a bad thing, or that requiring both GD and ImageMagick in your project does not represent an increase in dependencies?  The more "things" are involved in a project, the more complex it is.  More complexity means more opportunity for errors, and greater time to fix them.  Obviously you'd want to use a class or a function library to abstract as much as you can.  But that makes yet another "thing" to break and maintain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like this could be premature optimization, which increases code complexity, development time, and reduces maintainability.

Collect metrics based on actual usage. Find out:

- How often are you resizing small images?
- Where is the program spending the most time, where's the bottleneck?

Another downside is the opportunity cost. If small image resizing represents 5% of your use cases and the resizing step is 10% of that entire workflow, then your time will be better spent optimizing the 95% case where large images are resized or even in the other 90% of the workflow around resizing small images.